# change original URL to pretty URL with .htaccess file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I am trying to create pretty URL from my site, but I still newbie in **.htaccess**, I am so confuse to do it.

**Original URL:**

```
1. mysite.com/index.php?mode=frontend&act=viewArtikel&cat=hotnews&year=2017&month=02&link=hello-world

2. mysite.com/index.php?mode=frontend&act=viewProduct&cat=food&link=pizza
```

**Expected:**

```
1. mysite.com/hotnews/2017/02/hello-world.html
2. mysite.com/food/pizza.html
```

How to do it?
Thanks in advance
*ps: please don't mark this post duplicate, sorry for my bad English*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\d]{4}+)/([\d]{2}+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ index.php?mode=frontend&act=viewArtikel&cat=$1&year=$2&month=$3&link=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ index.php?mode=frontend&act=viewProduct&cat=$1&link=$2 [L]
```

Comment: where can i get reference about **w-** , **\d** ? by the way, can i define year and month only numeric with specific length exp: year [4 character] and month [2 character] ? , thanks in advance

Comment: `\w` matches letters, digits and underscore. `[\w-]` matches the same + a hyphen. Any character is matched with `.`. `[\d]` = `\d`. Also, `{2}+` / `{4}+` here can be replaced with `{2}` / `{4}` as the `+` makes the limiting quantifier *possessive*, which is not actually needed here.